# install ubuntu without dvd or usb

Tags: boot, usb, wubi

Very new to ubuntu. Absolute beginner. i know nothing.Using windows 10 and have downloaded ubuntu but am having trouble installing. Laptop does not have disc tray. Tried rufus to create booteable usb but it didn't work for some reason. Tried Wubi and was met with error "could not retrieve required disk image." Can anyone help me because I am a dumb baby. Thank you.

Comment: Rufus has a good reputation. Did you check with md5sum that the downloaded iso file is good? You can do it with Rufus (I think in the bottom right corner). You can also try to clone the iso file with Win32 Disk Imager. See this link, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb , and try Unetbootin as suggested in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try UNetbootin to create a bootable usb. It was way more easier than any other method. 
Download UNetbootin from its official website.

Comment: It is prompting me to pick a distribution?

Comment: @stevie - I recommend this: https://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.7.1.exe